# When I move to TabLayout index 2, Getdata SQLite Error

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, iot

I have some problem about my `TabLayout` And `SQLite`,

I work with IOT, MQTT,

when data publish from device, then data will be update to mysqlite and then show in listview.

It's Okay when I move to `TabLayout` Index 0 and Index 1, Problem is when I click `TabLayout` Index 3 and error showing when data read from `SQLite`.
error in

> `SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();`

MainActivity

```
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("AirConditioner"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Chiller"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("VoltMeter"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("AmpereMeter"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                //Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, getSupportFragmentManager().toString().trim(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
```

PagerAdapter

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import sems.idi.controllergospel.fragments.TabAC;
import sems.idi.controllergospel.fragments.TabAmper;
import sems.idi.controllergospel.fragments.TabChiller;
import sems.idi.controllergospel.fragments.TabVolt;

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabAC tab1 = new TabAC();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabChiller tab2 = new TabChiller();
                return tab2;
            case 2:
                TabVolt tab3 = new TabVolt();
                return tab3;
            case 3:
                TabAmper tab4 = new TabAmper();
                return tab4;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Publish From MQTT

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(new Intent("ListAC"));
```

TabAC Fragment

```
public class TabAC extends Fragment {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayAdapter<DataAc> adapter;
    List<DataAc> itemListAC = new ArrayList<DataAc>();
    AdapterAc adapterAc;
    Context context;

    public static TabAC newInstance() {
        return new TabAC();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_ac, container, false);


        initializeViews(v);
        loadData();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(ListAC,
                new IntentFilter("ListAC"));

        return v;
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver ListAC = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            loadData();
        }
    };
    /*
    INITIALIZE VIEWS
     */
    private void initializeViews(View rootView)
    {
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_ac);

        adapterAc = new AdapterAc(getActivity(), itemListAC);
        listView.setAdapter(adapterAc);
    }
    /*
    LOAD DATA
     */
    private void loadData()
    {

        itemListAC.clear();
        DbHelper SQLite = new DbHelper(getActivity());
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> row = SQLite.getDataAC();

        for (int i = 0; i < row.size(); i++) {
            String poster = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_KD);
            String title = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_TI);
            String title0 = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_TO);
            String title1 = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_AR);
            String title2 = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_SG);
            String title3 = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_DT);
            String title4 = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_PS);
            String title5 = row.get(i).get(DbHelper.F_TPA);

            DataAc data = new DataAc();

            data.setKD(poster);
            data.setTI(title);
            data.setTO(title0);
            data.setAR(title1);
            data.setSG(Integer.parseInt(title2));
            data.setDT(title3);
            data.setPS(title4);
            data.setTPA(title5);

            itemListAC.add(data);
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Kode Device" + poster + "|" + title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        adapterAc.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TabAc";
    }
}
```

Error In class DbHelper

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getDataAC() {

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> wordList;
        wordList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT KD, TI, TOs, AR, SG, DT, PS, TPA  FROM " + TABLE_Isems + " WHERE TP = '1'";
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(F_KD, cursor.getString(0));
                map.put(F_TI, cursor.getString(1));
                map.put(F_TO, cursor.getString(2));
                map.put(F_AR, cursor.getString(3));
                map.put(F_SG, cursor.getString(4));
                map.put(F_DT, cursor.getString(5));
                map.put(F_PS, cursor.getString(6));
                map.put(F_TPA, cursor.getString(7));

                wordList.add(map);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }


        Log.e("select sqlite ", "" + wordList);

        database.close();
        return wordList;
    }
```

Comment: `and error showing` which error?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you should close the Cursor when done with it e.g. after looping through the Cursor. Please edit your question and include the stack-trace.